# Multidex Error while useing google-play services

Tags: android, gradle, google-cloud-messaging, google-play

here is my error info:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define 
Lcom/google/android/gms/gcm/PendingCallback;
Error:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define 
Lcom/google/android/gms/gcm/PendingCallback;
Error:  at 
com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:60)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/gcm/PendingCallback;
```

My build.gradle dependency is :

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
//noinspection GradleCompatible
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportVersion}"
compile "com.android.support:design:${supportVersion}"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportVersion}"
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
// Logger  ADD
compile 'com.orhanobut:logger:2.1.1'
// network library
compile 'com.lzy.net:okgo:3.0.2'
// Toast upgrade version
compile 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.2.5'
//Img load library
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
// guide page library
compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
// Image Switcher MD rules Producted by ZHIHU Team
compile 'com.zhihu.android:matisse:0.4.3'
// leakcanary
debugCompile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:${leakcanary}"
releaseCompile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:${leakcanary}"
testCompile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:${leakcanary}"
// Firebase Analytics  install
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${firebase}"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${firebase}"
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.6.0'
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:${firebase}"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:${firebase}"
implementation files('libs/LiveChatWindow.jar')
```

AS sync is good, but when I start to install it, the error came out! I need use the google-play-service for the FCM to ensure the rate of the Firebase Cloud Messaging,yestoday test succeeds, today the error came out.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some methods, finally, find the solution for this issue;
here is my solution:
 1. According to the Google's guide change the

```
"com.google.android.gms:play-services:${firebase}"
```

to

```
"com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${firebase}"
```

2. delete all the build directory (project build & modules build )

3. rebuild the project